# True or false statement: For all $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $p$ prime we have that $a^p \equiv a \mod{p}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

> True or false statement: For all $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $p$ prime we
>   have that $a^p \equiv a \pmod{p}$

I formed it to $$a^p \bmod p = a \bmod p$$
and then inserted several different numbers and I always got the same result. Statement must be true but I don't really have a proof (not required because only a "yes" or "no" is needed). Anyway, I would be interested in knowing if I'm right and especially how this could be shown.

Comment: https://primes.utm.edu/notes/proofs/FermatsLittleTheorem.html

Answer (score 1):

It is true lets see why...

First we will look at the set of multiples of $a$ up to $(p-1)a$
$$X =  \{ka| k \in \mathbb Z \,0<k<p\} $$

Lemma: $\forall x \in X$, there doesnt not exist another distinct element $y$ such that $y \equiv x$ $(mod$ $p)$

Proof: assume there does exist an element $x = ra$ and a distinct element $y = sa$ that belong to $X$ such that $y \equiv x$ $(mod$ $p)$. This implies $sa \equiv ra$ $(mod$ $p)$ $\implies$ $r \equiv s$ $(mod$ $p)$ $\implies$ $r = s$. This leads to a contradiction as that means $x$ would be equal to $y$.

Using the lemma, we can say that $$\prod_{x_i \in X}x_i = \prod_{k=1}^{p-1}ka \equiv (1)(2)(3)(4)...(p-1)\space \space\space (mod \space p)$$
since each $ka$ must be distinct and there are $p-1$ of them
$$\implies a^{p-1}((p-1)!)\equiv (p-1)!\space \space\space (mod \space p)$$
$$\implies a^{p-1} \equiv1\space \space\space (mod \space p)$$

Q.E.D.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know Euler's formula and theorem? 
Euler's formula is $\phi(p)$={number of numbers that are relatively prime to p and are below p}

and Euler's theorem is $a^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1 \pmod n$

The demonstration follows that:

If p|a then $a^p \equiv a \equiv 0 \pmod p$
Otherwise $\phi(p) = p-1 $and $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$ by Euler's theorem. 
So $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p \implies a^p \equiv a \pmod p$

And that proves the statment

Comment: "Euler's formula is $\phi(p)$={number of divisors of p}" Not really

Comment: $\phi (n) =$ the number of integers below $n$ such that they are relatively prime to $n$ AKA have no common divisors.

Comment: I've studied that a long time ago. Thank you by the help :)

Comment: Also, Euler's theorem only works for $a$ relatively prime to $n$, and has $1$ on the right hand side of the congruence.

Comment: I don't know why I wrote 0 xD